# Is it possible for Vue.js to automatically update the view when a third-party JSON is updated?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

*I'm trying to accomplish the following but I don't even know if it is even possible with Vue as I'm struggling to get the desired result:*

I have an endpoint for an API which returns many objects within an array.

I am successfully rendering the data within my Vue application but I wanted to know if it is possible for Vue to "track" when the array has been updated with more objects and then render those in the view.

I am using `setInterval` to perform a GET request every 10 minutes and the new data is going into the object within my `data()` correctly but the changes are not reflected within the view.

At the moment I am changing a boolean from `true` to `false` at the beginning and end respectively so that the view is rendered again with `v-if`.

My goal is to create a simple Twitter feed app that performs a GET request every 10 minutes, collects the tweets, puts them into my Vue instance and show them in the view without having to reload the page/re-render the component. Like an automatic Twitter feed that just constantly loads new tweets every 10 minutes.

Is this even possible? I've tried using the `Vue.set()` method but that hasn't made any difference.

If it's not possible, what would be the best way to implement something similar?

Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [],
  },
  created() {
    this.load();
    setInterval(() => this.load(), 5000);
  },
  methods: {
    load() {
      axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
      .then(response => {
        this.items = response.data.data;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.first_name }}
  </p>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/tomhartley97/pen/VwZpZNG

In the above code, if the array is updated by the GET request, the chances are not reflected within the view?

Comment: You should add some code to your question.

Comment: If your question has been full answered please accept the answer so it's visible to others :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The way you need to set new reactive properties in your Vue instance is the following:

For Object properties: `Vue.set(this.baseObject, key, value)` 
The baseObject cannot be a Vue instance or the base data() object, so you will have to declare a container property.

For Array entries use native array methods: e.g. `Array.prototype.push()`.
Using `Vue.set(array, arrayIndex, newArrayElement)` does not work

Hence, your solution might look something line that:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      response: [],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    setInterval = (() => this.getData), 600000);
  }

  methods: {
    async getData() {
      const res = await request();
      const resLength = res.data.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < resLength; i++) {
        // check if entry is already in array
        const entryExists = this.response.some((entry) => {
          return entry.id === res.data[i].id
        })
        if (!entryExists) {
          // this will make the array entries responsive, but not nested Objects
          this.response.push(res.data[i]);
          // to create nested responsive Objects you will have to set them explicitly
          // e.g. Vue.set(this.response[this.response.indexOf(res.data[i])], nestedObjectKey, res.data[i].nestedObject)
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would imagine this would work in the way using axios? Can your getData() method work if it is turned into a promise? Also, I am correct in thinking that the Vue.set() method tells Vue that a new object has been added to the array and should update the view accordingly?

Comment: Vue.set() does not work with arrays. You can only set object properties with the method. And it does register a getter+setter for the property instead of just setting a value.

Comment: What your getData method does is not relevant to making new state reactive within Vue. But yes, it could make an axios request/await a promise and then set the value (as in my example)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I view the codepen, I known why your view do not get update: the api response always return the same array!

Try to return different data.

---

The api returns an array, so the `data` defines

```js
data() {
  return {
    array: [] // array that api returns
  }
}
```

The template may look like this

```html
<div v-for="item in array">
</div>
```

And the update methods

```js
update() {
  setInterval(async () => {
    let resp = await api()

    this.array = resp.data.concat(this.array)

  }, TEN_MINUTES)
}
```